# Render Full Calendar of DatePicker on a page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, calendar, material-ui

I'm trying out React to make a simple application.

I like how the full calendar looks like of the following date pickers (after clicking):

- [Material-UI](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/date-picker)
- [React-Toolbox](http://react-toolbox.com/#/components/date_picker)

Is it possible to extract out the full calendar out onto a page without having to click to open the calendar modal/dialog? Just like in Google Calendar apps.

For example, I'd like to display the calendar on the main page of the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Calendar component](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/date-picker/calendar.jsx) in material-ui library. You should be able to use it directly -

`import Calendar from 'material-ui/lib/date-picker/calendar';`

For an example on how to use it, look inside the [DatePickerDialog component code](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/date-picker/date-picker-dialog.jsx).

```
<Calendar
      DateTimeFormat={DateTimeFormat}
      firstDayOfWeek={firstDayOfWeek}
      locale={locale}
      ref="calendar"
      onDayTouchTap={this.handleTouchTapDay}
      initialDate={this.props.initialDate}
      open={this.state.open}
      minDate={this.props.minDate}
      maxDate={this.props.maxDate}
      shouldDisableDate={this.props.shouldDisableDate}
      disableYearSelection={this.props.disableYearSelection}
      mode={this.props.mode}
    />
```

Comment: Hey thanks! That's what I did after digging through the source code. Thanks again

Comment: Glad to know that. Please accept the answer if it helped.