# Render Calendar without opening a dialog/modal for Material-UI React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, calendar, material-ui

I'm trying to render Material-UI calendar component without opening a dialog as demonstrated in all picker examples in material-ui-next demo page.

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35378272/render-full-calendar-of-datepicker-on-a-page), however the answer's import line doesn't apply anymore for beta version, and furthermore I couldn't find src files of beta version on github, nor the way to import pure calendar component.

Is it not possible to do such thing in v1 beta? If not, should I just use the older version?

Actually, I'm trying to use the calendar component under tab implementations like below, with different calendar dates pick range options as day, week, month, year; which I'll then try to implement out of that Calendar component I'm looking to render. So I thought finding out that component would be the first step to my solution.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

[image]

[image: Week Range Calendar]     [image: Year range calendar] etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible right now, and is a known issue. You can see it here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/4787 and https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/4796.

It is being discussed for a long time and probably will be in a release soon.

You can use a older version until that update or just use the modal with beta, until a new release.

Comment: oh thanks for the answer Victor! Just a quick followup here then, is it possible to use both versions at the same time? or should I just roll back to older version completely in my project?

Comment: also aren't the src files released until it is an official version?

Comment: I do not know about using both at the same time, never tried. You can try it, but I believe they can have conflicts between them. Also, it is an open source project, you can get the src whenever you want too, but they can be buggy. When they are released means that they are in a stable version